# Android - Choosing a option shown by circle shaped touch objects

Tags: android, object, button, geometry, shapes

I have provided a picture below so you can get a better understanding. Basically I want the user to pick a number from 1-10 which is shown by circles (Only 1 number can be picked at a  time). Lets say I pick number 10, as you can see on the picture I want the circle to stroke and change the color when the number is picked (indicating to the user that the number has been chosen). After the number is picked and you press the "blue button", I want to **get the value picked** to do other calculations.

[This is how I want it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6ttw.png)

I feel having a touch based circle is the best way to do it, rather than using a spinner because it take more time. Now the question is how to do this without code duplication or redundancy and how to achieve this in the best way possible. I am thinking I have to create a circle object (Possibly button shaped like circles) 10 times and put text on them, group them in array?..etc or is there a more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's better ways to achieve this but I suggest a simple solution as you wanted !!!

> Now the question is how to do this without code duplication or redundancy?

You can create a `xml` file in your `drawable` folder and put two different oval `shape`s in that: `defaultShape` and `pickedShape`, Use `<solid>` and `<stroke>` tags to customize your shapes as you like, and then apply it to your buttons' `background`.

In order to handle the picking of your button you should implement same `onClickListener`for all 10 buttons, if one of them is picked save it to a temp variable like `Button pickedButton`, in your listener your check if `pickedButton` is not `null` change its background to `defaultShape`, and assign the new picked one to the `pickedButton` and then change its `background` to `pickedShape`.

Hope you find it helpful.